# Creating PDF with tcpdf shows blank on iphone

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to produce PDF's from HTML. Everything is working fine and when I view the PDF on my computer I can see it just fine, but for some reason when I look at the PDF on my iPhone it shows up blank. All I can see are the borders I created that contain values in them but there are no values showing.

Here is my code

```
require_once('/tcpdf/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('/tcpdf/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.website.com/invoice.php?invoice_id='.$invoice_id);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('/html/admin/emailattachements/invoice.pdf', 'F');
```

In that last line. I copy the PDF to that directory when I grab it later with an email script and sends it off to a customer.

[image: Blank PDF]

Edit: SOLVED

I discovered it was the font I was using to produce the PDF. iPhone's can't read dejavusans :) I changed it to 'times' and it works fine

**Edit: Update**

Since this article I have had to create many more PDF's with tcpdf and while I can't really explain why some fonts were not working while others where I recently applied some of the suggestions over at http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php and applied

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/DejaVuSans.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

By adding a font manually and setting the font file path and uploading the file manually I was able to get existing font's that did not work and actually get them to work.

Comment: Ummmm... what's your code so we can perhaps duplicate the effort.

Comment: added my code to the original question

Comment: now that I look at it I wonder if it is the font

Comment: lol that was it. It's the font :) I changed it to 'times' and it works

Comment: I am not so sure it's that easy to explain why it's not working... I have two almost identical documents. One works with dejavusans, the other does not. Changing to `helvetica` works.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with a custom font. I haven't found a solution.

Comment: For iOS6 font lists: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5484

Comment: I've also encountered this problem with akeebasubs invoices (it makes use of tcpdf). The problem occurred on an iphone running ios5 and an ipad running ios7.

Answer (score 2):

Change the below lines:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
```

To:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10, '', true);
```

And then check.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how its working for you without the AddFont method, but I had the same issue and adding the fourth param $subset = false fixes it.

> $subset (mixed) if true embedd only a subset of the font (stores only
>   the information related to the used characters); if false embedd full
>   font; if 'default' uses the default value set using
>   setFontSubsetting(). This option is valid only for TrueTypeUnicode
>   fonts. If you want to enable users to change the document, set this
>   parameter to false. If you subset the font, the person who receives
>   your PDF would need to have your same font in order to make changes to
>   your PDF. The file size of the PDF would also be smaller because you
>   are embedding only part of a font.

```
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans', '', 'dejavusans', false);
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans', 'B', 'dejavusans', false);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
```

dejavusans fixes a number of issues with multibyte characters so not possible to simple change to helvetica. By making this change we found the PDF to more than double in size.

This is kinda the same idea as @user3548394 but only have to make this change once.

Comment: Wow size more than doubles 16kb to 734kb

Answer (score 0):

Check the font type you are using, is like html, but it won't fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Create pdf with static text and check.